# Log multiple values and use the log to send a daily report with only recent changes as well as a compiled email on a specific date with all data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been able to write the following code which based on an installable trigger (daily) checks for the word "backorder" on column "M" in the first 100 rows. If it finds a row with the matching criteria it will grab the info from 3 other columns  (customer name, project name, project $) for the particular row and then email that information out. So far that appears to work well.

What Im trying to accomplish is the following;

1- If column M reads "backorder" then copy rows for columns I, J and K and send all data at once via email daily(Thanks to @Gerneio this works now)

2- Same as Goal 1 but only for new items (not previously emailed items)

3- Send a report at the end of the week with ALL items logged during the week

Is this possible?

[Published sheet link](https://docs.google.com/a/itechavs.com/spreadsheets/d/1fbbgzAb1LLWnsUwlxzHd5WAAooasDozExxTmcXJ4x-c/pubhtml)

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsrVv.png) (Picture)

```
   function backorder2()
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var col = 13;

// start table and add header cells and row
var html = "<table><tr><th>Customer</th><th>Project</th><th>$ Amt</th></tr>";

for (var row2 = 1;row2 <=100; row2++)
{
var rownumber = sheet.getRange(row2,col);
var customer = sheet.getRange(row2,col-4).getValue();
var project = sheet.getRange(row2,col-3).getValue();
var $ = sheet.getRange(row2,col-2).getValue();
var timestamp = new Date();
timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT-05:00", "MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss");

if (rownumber.getValue() == "backorder")
{
sheet.getRange(row2,col).setNote(timestamp);

html += "<tr>";
html += "<td>" + customer + "</td>";
html += "<td>" + project + "</td>";
html += "<td>$" + $ + "</td>";
html += "</tr>";
}
else
{
sheet.getRange(row2,col).clearNote();
}
}

html += "</table>";

MailApp.sendEmail('you@gmail.com', 'Backorders on project', 'Following projects have items on backorder:', {htmlBody : html});
}
```

---

Comment:  I wouldn't have updated the whole entire question just for other people who come along in search of a similar question and answer, but rather add update sections below original question. But that's ok, we can work with that haha.

Comment: Also, you are right, the sheets are restricted. Perhaps just take a screenshot of the general sheet or copy and paste a sample data set.

Comment: The published link should work but I also included a picture with the same data as suggested. I appreciate the patience helping me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How frequently are you wanting the email sent out? Same time frame as that backorder() trigger already runs, so daily? Or another time frame? If it is the same time frame, and assuming that the only criteria that qualifies for grouping is if it list "backorder", then the simplest way is to concatenate all your rows into a formatted html table.

**Updated Code:**

```
function backorder()
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var col = 13;

var dayOfWeekForWeekly = 'Sunday';

var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

var timestamp = new Date();
//timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT-05:00", "MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss");

  // in case weekly report is needed
  var maxDateBound = new Date(timestamp.getFullYear(), timestamp.getMonth(), timestamp.getDate() + 1);
  var minDateBound = new Date(maxDateBound.getFullYear(), maxDateBound.getMonth(), maxDateBound.getDate() - 7);

// start table and add header cells and row
var html = "<table><tr><th>Customer</th><th>Project</th><th>$ Amt</th></tr>";

var validRowExist = false;

for (var row2 = 1;row2 <=100; row2++)
{
var rownumber = sheet.getRange(row2,col);
var customer = sheet.getRange(row2,col-4).getValue();
var project = sheet.getRange(row2,col-3).getValue();
var $ = sheet.getRange(row2,col-2).getValue();

var existingNote = rownumber.getNote();
var existingTimestamp = null;
if (existingNote != "")
  existingTimestamp = new Date(existingNote);    

var isValidRowForDaily = (rownumber.getValue() == "backorder" && existingNote == "");
var isValidRowForWeekly = (rownumber.getValue() == "backorder" && days[timestamp.getDay()] == dayOfWeekForWeekly && (existingTimestamp >= minDateBound && existingTimestamp < maxDateBound));

if (isValidRowForDaily || isValidRowForWeekly)
{
rownumber.setNote(timestamp);

html += "<tr>";
html += "<td>" + customer + "</td>";
html += "<td>" + project + "</td>";
html += "<td>$" + $ + "</td>";
html += "</tr>";
validRowExist = true;
}
else if (rownumber.getValue() != "backorder")
{
rownumber.clearNote();
}
}

html += "</table>";

var subject = "";

if (validRowExist)
{
if (days[timestamp.getDay()] == dayOfWeekForWeekly)
{
  subject = "Weekly Backorders on Projects: ";
  subject += minDateBound.toDateString() + " - ";
  subject += timestamp.toDateString();
}
else
{
  subject = "Daily Backorders on Project: ";
  subject += timestamp.toDateString();
}

MailApp.sendEmail('me@gmail.com', subject, 'Following projects have these items on backorder:', {htmlBody : html});
}
}
else
{
   // write code to send follow up email since table is empty
 }
```

**Update - See above for code referring to daily and weekly emails of new entries only. There are tons of ways to approach this, and perhaps some are more suitable than what I got for you here. But you can give the above a try. Essentially what it does is rely on the note that you set with a date each time you send an email with applicable rows. At the end of the week (in this case I used Sunday, which you can change near the top) a report will be generated for the entire week including all the new entries of that day. I hope this is what you were looking for.**

Comment: *Hit enter too soon.* The email will in fact be sent daily but only with the new items.  Im working on this script in steps. My next step is to figure out how to send a weekly report with all backorders for the week and daily emails of only new ones. Im thinking of adding a tag via setNote() and then have the script ignore the lines that have that tag, what are your thoughts?. BTW, since Im new to stackoverflow, Im not sure if I should create a new question for the above or continue this one?

Comment: We'll continue with this post. Can you edit your original question and add a sample data set for what your sheet looks like so that I can get an idea of what we are working with.

Comment: Absolutely. Take a look above.

Comment: You nailed it sir. I appreciate the attention to detail as well. (i.e. adding the date range on the email subject.

Comment: As a note. I had to comment out the timestamp formatting because otherwise it would give an error. //timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT-05:00", "MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss");. the script appears to work fine with the limited testing that I did, however, Im not sure if that may have other implications.

Comment: Awesome! Just paying my dues . Just keep an eye on it and see how it performs over a weeks time.

Comment: as a last comment, I made a couple very minor corrections. Should I send them to you so you can upload as final answer for others to see in the future?  i.e. += for subject on else.  else
{
  subject = "Daily Backorders on Project: ";
  subject += timestamp.toDateString();

Comment: Also it probably errors out because id imagine the Utilities.formatDate() outputs a formatted string of some sorts. Just a guess, not a conclusion though.

Comment: I knew I'd be missing some little things like that! I'll correct it real quick.

Comment: I found a way to edit your original response. Looks like you just need to approve it and it should be good to go. I really appreciate all your help with this. I hope this helps others in the future too. It is a great script to send notifications.

Comment: Gerneio, as I keep testing the sheet another question just came up. Is there a way to check if the HTML table is empty? I'm thinking that instead of sending a blank email when there are no changes I could send an email with a different body. Just something that states no changes have been made. that email would just serve as a note that nothing has changed but script is still running.

Comment: Check updated code above. Meant to add that, just forgot along the way.

Comment: It works great. Once again, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi Gerneio, Im working on a few other spreadsheet scripts and I would like to know if you would be interested in helping us out with this as a project. I can share with you the scope and the data and you can give us a price. Let me know. Thanks,