# Don't Run Script on Sundays

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a Script that runs on a daily trigger in Google Sheets , pulling data from one spreadsheet and stores it in another.

It's working wonderfully, but I need it to not run on Sundays. I can't quite figure out how to validate the date and only run the script Monday-Saturday.

```
    function copyDailyreport() {
var timeStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");

var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MSM");
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MSM Daily Totals");
var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(4, 11, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

//convert the column to a row
valuesToCopy=valuesToCopy.join('*#*');
valuesToCopy=valuesToCopy.split('*#*');

//add timestamp in the first place in the row
valuesToCopy.unshift(timeStamp)

//add the row to destination sheet
sheetTo.appendRow(valuesToCopy);




var timeStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");

var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SM");
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SM Daily Totals");
var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(4, 11, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

//convert the column to a row
valuesToCopy=valuesToCopy.join('*#*');
valuesToCopy=valuesToCopy.split('*#*');

//add timestamp in the first place in the row
valuesToCopy.unshift(timeStamp)

//add the row to destination sheet
sheetTo.appendRow(valuesToCopy);



var timeStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");

var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SH");
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SH Daily Totals");
var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(4, 11, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

//convert the column to a row
valuesToCopy=valuesToCopy.join('*#*');
valuesToCopy=valuesToCopy.split('*#*');

//add timestamp in the first place in the row
valuesToCopy.unshift(timeStamp)

//add the row to destination sheet
sheetTo.appendRow(valuesToCopy);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648407/1595451

Comment: Thanks, I'll read through all of this!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by using [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Set it manually 6 time-driven trigger with week timer, one for each day from Monday to Saturday.

Another way is to set it manually 1 time-driven trigger that runs every day, but do a check on your script on whether it is Sunday

```
var currentDay = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E");
if (currentDay !== "Sun") {
    // execute the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas! I was thinking a script to check/validate the day of the week would probably be the route I would go, ai was just having some issues executing it.

Comment: Then the code in my answer would be sufficient to check whether it is Sunday or not. Just insert your current code inside the `if` function, so that it only execute on non-Sunday days